# javascript multiply currency with number

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML;
var total = a * b
document.getElementById("ttl").innerHTML = total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

```html
<p id="price">1,460,000</p>
<p id="qty">2</p>
<p id="ttl"></p>
```

It work well,but problem is content of ID-price,because i need output like this 2,920,000.(its price * qty),but in indonesian rupiah currency format.
I want to ask,how can "unformat" that price and then make calculation then format again?
Because if i put 1,460,000 without "," my code work well,but how can i count with "," ,and have output with "," ?

Comment: Multiplying will only work on contiguous digits. But your "price" element has commas

Comment: Numeric values should be kept as numbers, not as formatted strings.  If your variables contain numbers you can perform all the math on them that you like.  Then when *displaying* the value you would format it for human-readability.

Comment: Always store numeric values as it is, when you are showing you can show with comma separated values!

Comment: Yes,but how can i format that summary before displaying it for the user?

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: @andrewniewiem: *"but how can i format that summary before displaying it"* - A Google search for "javascript format number" or "javascript format currency" finds *tons* of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML;

//convert to number
a = Number(a.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
b = Number(b.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));  

var total = a * b;
//convert string again
document.getElementById("ttl").innerHTML = total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

```html
<p id="price">1,460,000</p>
<p id="qty">2</p>
<p id="ttl"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Number formatters

```
let currencyFormatterInteger = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
    style: "currency",
    currency: currency,
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  });

currencyFormatterInteger.format(price / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will remove the commas and convert it to float which can be formatted.

```
parseFloat('100,000.00'.replace(/,/g, ''));
```